# TV show involving a town where only the kids and adults up to age 21 are alive

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I know ID questions are not good questions to ask but for the life of I can't remember the name of this TV series.

I saw it on either Hulu or Netflix (but don't see it in any of my queues), earlier this year or late last year.  It was a newer series, probably last 2-3 years, and it was only one season that I was able to watch.  It may have been on one of the major networks like ABC or Fox, or one of the cable networks like AMC or TNT or something.  I can't be for sure because I don't subscribe to cable.

It involved a town where only the kids and adults up to age 21 were alive.  Something happened when they turned 21, some kind of conspiracy might have been involved.  2 factions break out, one involving the well off kids taking charge of town and a group of outcasts from the wrong side of town.  I think the town may have been quarantined.

Really curious to remember, I want to know if there is/was a season 2 or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're most probably after [Between](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_(TV_series)), that is being distributed by Netflix:

> The series stars Jennette McCurdy as Wiley Day, a pregnant teenage
>   daughter of a minister living in the small town of Pretty Lake, which
>   is coping with a mysterious disease which has killed everybody who is
>   over 21 years old. The series is a co-production with Netflix, who
>   distributes the series outside of Canada as a Netflix original series.

Indeed the town is under quarantine:

> In the
>   trailer for Netflix’s upcoming show Between, a plague sweeps through
>   the small town of Pretty Lake, killing everyone over a certain age and
>   forcing the young survivors to live in quarantine, without adult
>   supervision.

([source](http://io9.gizmodo.com/in-netflix-show-between-a-plague-kills-all-adults-in-a-1704331120))

Netflix [confirmed](http://netflixlife.com/2016/05/25/between-season-2-is-coming-to-netflix-in-july/) that the series will come back with second season in July 2016.

Comment: Dang it, you beat me by a minute.  If you add in the info about the second-season release (see [here,](http://netflixlife.com/2016/05/25/between-season-2-is-coming-to-netflix-in-july/)) I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Done, although no need to delete your answer.